# Using loop to generate String Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I have start of loop and end of loop like int i=0 when initialized and loop should continue until i=99.

With each iteration I need to generate String with value of i like `Sk+i`.
With each iteration it should generate values like

```
sk001
sk002
...
sk099
```

and not only this string this loop should generate it in an specific form like

```
<register><name>sk001</name>
  <name>sk002</name>
  ...
  <name>sk099</name>
</register>
```

How can I achieve it in Jmeter?

Comment: I didn't try anything because I got no idea how to do it as am a new user of Jmeter, I have been learning Jmeter since last manth. I think we need to use RegEx but don't know how and where use it and which controller should I use.

Comment: I need to do something like that http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Concatenate-variable-list-returned-in-HTTP-GET-td5453990.html ...but not sure how to write " beanshell Post Processr to loop through the regex result and form 
the String in java. " as suggested in this post. Could you folks please help?

Comment: I've done all the way to loop and regex result but couldn't find how to concatenate new value with the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it using BeanShell Sampler

```
String authString ="<name>" + "${name}" + "</name>";

String temp=vars.get("acc");

vars.put("acc",temp+authString);
```

where ${name} is the value i get from iterating array of names.

It will concatenate old and new values.